# uninitialized constant for Model when testing Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first project in rails, and for some reason I fail to create my first unit test for my controller.

Basically, I have a main object Election, and each election may contain many voters.
The voters are created from a comma separated list of emails.

In this test, I want to test several lists of emails, to be sure that they are ingested correctly. 
But for a reason I can't really grasp, my Voter model is not detected by my controller test.

So here is the related part of the code :

**voters_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class VotersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    test "should add new voters" do
        assert_difference('Voters.count', 2) do
            post :create, voter: {election_id: 1, email_list: "me@me.fr, you@you.com"}
        end
    end
end
```

**voter.rb**

```
class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :email_list
    belongs_to :election

    validates :email, presence: true, :email => true
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => [:election_id]
end
```

and the controller, **voters_controller.rb**

```
class VotersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @election = Election.find(params[:election_id])
    end

    def create
        @election = Election.find(params[:election_id])

        emails = voter_params[:email_list].squish.split(',')
        emails.each { |email| @voter = @election.voters.create(:email =>email) }

        redirect_to election_voters_path(@election)

    end

    private

        def voter_params
            params.require(:voter).permit(:email_list)
        end

end
```

I should probably mention that my application works fine, and that only the test is failing.

The exact error message is :

```
Run options: --seed 24993

# Running:

E.

Finished in 0.098560s, 20.2922 runs/s, 10.1461 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
VotersControllerTest#test_should_add_new_voters:
NameError: uninitialized constant VotersControllerTest::Voters
    /home/jll/Documents/01_perso/00_myelections/test/controllers/voters_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:VotersControllerTest>'
```

This it is my very first ruby test, I heavily inspired myself from [the rails testing tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers).

Could you please provide me some insight on what I do wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is your exact error??

Comment: HA, yeah, I forgot the most important part ^^. Editing my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assert the difference on the `Voters` model instead of the `Voter` model. This is what the code should look like.

```
assert_difference('Voter.count', 2) do
  ...
end
```

Remember, models will bear the singular version of the resource name while controllers will bear the plural name. E.g. The model is `Voter` while the controller is `VotersController`.

Comment: Ha, you're right. The error vanishes when I switch to Voter.count. I am still a bit confused on when use the singular or the plural :). Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you got it working. After a while, that will all become second nature!